# Vue js event not picked up

Tags: vue.js, symfony, vue-component

I have just started experimenting with vue js and I am building a checkout form with it. I am also using `Symfony 31` for the project. On the checkout/signup page I have an embedded collection of forms representing order items (each are subscription to a type of product). You can select multiple items by ticking a checkbox. You can also change the quantity. Unfortunately I cannot manage to pass the quantity update to the `Vue` instance. The entries are registered on render with the quantity 1, and if I change the quantity and then select the item, the price is calculated correctly, but the app registers this as a new entity. The binding with the quantity is not working. I will also need to add a similar field called frequency and I know I will have the same problem. Help?

Here is the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wavsu8xm/

Javascript:

```
var bus = new Vue();

var entriesComponent = Vue.component('entries', {
  template: '#entries',
  props: {
    entries: [Array, Object],
    selected: Array,
    addons: Array,
    frequencies: [Array, Object],
  },
  watch: {
    selected: function(val, oldVal) {
      bus.$emit('selected-changed', val);
    },
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    entries: [],
    selected: [],
    addons: [],
    frequencies: [],
    paymentConfig: {
      advance: 25,
      firstweek: 25,
      ondelivery: 50,
    },
    weeks: 12,
  },
  components: {
    'entriesComponent': entriesComponent,
  },
  created: function() {
    // store this to use with Vue.set
    var temp = this;
    bus.$on('selected-changed', function(selected) {
      // vm.$set deprecated
      Vue.set(temp, 'selected', selected);
    });
  },
  computed: {
    totalAdvance: function() {
      return (this.paymentConfig.advance * this.total) / 100;
    },
    totalFirstWeek: {
      get: function() {
        return (this.paymentConfig.firstweek * this.total) / 100;
      },
    },
    onDeliveryPayment: {
      get: function() {
        return (this.paymentConfig.ondelivery * this.total) / (this.weeks * 100);
      }
    },
    total: {
      get: function() {
        var sum = 0;
        var weeks = this.weeks;
        this.selected.forEach(function(item) {
          sum += weeks * item.itemPrice * item.quantity;
        });
        console.log(sum);
        return sum;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<section class="content">
  <div class="row" id="app">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label required">Items</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <entries :entries="{ 0 : { shareSize : 'Small', quantity : '1', itemPrice : '24', frequency : '' }, 1 : { shareSize : 'Medium', quantity : '1', itemPrice : '35', frequency : '' }, 2 : { shareSize : 'Large', quantity : '1', itemPrice : '46', frequency : '' } }"
                  :selected="selected"></entries>
                  <!-- component template -->
                  <template id="entries">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group" v-for="(entry, key) in entries" v-bind:entry="entry">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                              <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="entry" v-model="selected">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">{{entry.shareSize}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">{{'$ ' + Number(entry.itemPrice).toFixed(2) }}</div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input type="number" v-model="entry.quantity" :value="entry.quantity" />
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </template>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box box-info">
          <div class="box-body" style="padding:15px;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="control-label">
                  <label>Summary</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-control" v-for="item in selected">
                  <span class="pull-left small-box-footer">{{ item.shareSize }}</span>
                  <span class="pull-right">{{ item.quantity + ' x $ ' + (item.itemPrice*item.quantity).toFixed(2)}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="control-label">
                  <label>Payment plan</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  {{ '$ ' + totalAdvance.toFixed(2) }} - advance
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  {{ '$ ' + totalFirstWeek.toFixed(2) }} - first week
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  {{ '$ ' + onDeliveryPayment.toFixed(2) }}/ week on each of the {{ weeks }} weeks of the subscription
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 row">
                  <div class="control-label"><strong><span class="pull-left">Total</span><span class="pull-right">{{ '$ ' + total.toFixed(2) }}</span></strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 row">
                  <div class="title"><strong><span class="pull-left">Total due now</span><span class="pull-right">{{ '$ ' + totalAdvance.toFixed(2) }}</span></strong></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating your props directly which will get overwritten when the parent component re-renders, so you need to make a copy of them inside your component, which can be done inside the created method of your component:

```
  created: function() {
    // copy props to data
    this.entriesCopy = this.entries;
    this.selectedCopy = this.selected;
  },
  data: function() {
    return{
     entriesCopy: [],
     selectedCopy: []
    }
  }
```

Now you just need to update your watcher:

```
  watch: {
    selectedCopy: function(val, oldVal) {
      bus.$emit('selected-changed', val);
    }
  }
```

And your template:

```
//...
div class="form-group" v-for="(entry, key) in entriesCopy" v-bind:entry="entry">
//...
<input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="entry" v-model="selectedCopy">
```

to reflect the changes.

Here's the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5pyw74h9/

Comment: Thanks so much! It works now! 
Minor update: data(){ should be written data: function() {

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm using `Ecmascript 6` syntax, which needs to be compiled through something like [babel](https://babeljs.io) for use in a browser, I'll update the answer and use `Ecmascript 5` instead.

Comment: I have a further question. Should I add it here or make a new one?
Say I want to add two elements of type <entries> (same component) to the page, but I want both of them to write to the same selected array. 
(The selected property in the main view should be the union of the two elements)

Comment: @anegrea could you please post that in a new question, as it's going to be difficult to answer that here. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746450/vue-js-combing-the-elements-from-two-components Many thanks in advance!