# Vue js combining the elements from two components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to build the checkout page of a e-commerce type of app. On the checkout I have a list of OrderItems coming from the database, each with price, quantity. You can pick and combine these. In addition I have to render somewhere else a list with "addons" to your basket. This are also OrderItems (same properties) but have a different type.

I have a Vue.js component for rendering an array of OrderItems from which you can pick. The way I though of this is rendering the same component twice. However the "selected" property takes models either form one list or the other, but not from both at the same time. I would like the selected prop to hold items from both lists (simple orderItems and addons)

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w8vfb64L/

The code:

Template:

```
<section class="content">
  <div class="row" id="app">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label required">Items</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
<entries :entries="{ 0 : { shareSize : 'Small', quantity : '1', itemPrice : '24', frequency : '' }, 1 : { shareSize : 'Medium', quantity : '1', itemPrice : '35', frequency : '' }, 2 : { shareSize : 'Large', quantity : '1', itemPrice : '46', frequency : '' } }"
                  :selected="selected"></entries>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label class="control-label required">Addons</label>
                  <entries :entries="{ 0 : { shareSize : 'Large', quantity : '1', itemPrice : '46', frequency : '' } }" :selected="selected"></entries>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box box-info">
          <div class="box-body" style="padding:15px;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="control-label">
                  <label>Summary</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-control" v-for="item in selected">
                  <span class="pull-left small-box-footer">{{ item.shareSize }}</span>
                  <span class="pull-right">{{ item.quantity + ' x $ ' + (item.itemPrice*item.quantity).toFixed(2)}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="control-label">
                  <label>Payment plan</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  {{ '$ ' + totalAdvance.toFixed(2) }} - advance
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  {{ '$ ' + totalFirstWeek.toFixed(2) }} - first week
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  {{ '$ ' + onDeliveryPayment.toFixed(2) }}/ week on each of the {{ weeks }} weeks of the subscription
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 row">
                  <div class="control-label"><strong><span class="pull-left">Total</span><span class="pull-right">{{ '$ ' + total.toFixed(2) }}</span></strong></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 row">
                  <div class="title"><strong><span class="pull-left">Total due now</span><span class="pull-right">{{ '$ ' + totalAdvance.toFixed(2) }}</span></strong></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- component template -->
<template id="entries">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group" v-for="(entry, key) in entriesCopy" v-bind:entry="entry">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="entry" v-model="selectedCopy">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">{{entry.shareSize}}</div>
          <div class="col-md-4">{{'$ ' + Number(entry.itemPrice).toFixed(2) }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="number" v-model="entry.quantity" :value="entry.quantity" />
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
var bus = new Vue();

var entriesComponent = Vue.component('entries', {
  template: '#entries',
  props: {
    entries: [Array, Object],
    selected: Array,
    addons: Array,
    frequencies: [Array, Object],
  },
  created: function() {
    this.entriesCopy = this.entries;
    this.selectedCopy = this.selected;
  },
  watch: {
    selectedCopy: function(val, oldVal) {
      bus.$emit('selected-changed', val);
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      entriesCopy: [],
      selectedCopy: [] 
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    entries: [],
    selected: [],
    addons: [],
    frequencies: [],
    paymentConfig: {
      advance: 25,
      firstweek: 25,
      ondelivery: 50,
    },
    weeks: 12,
  },
  components: {
    'entriesComponent': entriesComponent,
  },
  created: function() {
    // store this to use with Vue.set
    var temp = this;
    bus.$on('selected-changed', function(selected) {
      // vm.$set deprecated
      Vue.set(temp, 'selected', selected);
    });
  },
  computed: {
    totalAdvance: function() {
      return (this.paymentConfig.advance * this.total) / 100;
    },
    totalFirstWeek: {
      get: function() {
        return (this.paymentConfig.firstweek * this.total) / 100;
      },
    },
    onDeliveryPayment: {
      get: function() {
        return (this.paymentConfig.ondelivery * this.total) / (this.weeks * 100);
      }
    },
    total: {
      get: function() {
        var sum = 0;
        var weeks = this.weeks;
        this.selected.forEach(function(item) {
          sum += weeks * item.itemPrice * item.quantity;
        });
        console.log(sum);
        return sum;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: At the moment I managed to add a separate variable to the component called addons. But this is a bit redundant from my point of view.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're doing. Where are your `OrderItems` ? What's the problem ?

Comment: I'll edit the question to add some more info. Sorry about that @Elfayer

Comment: @anegrea what is expected behaviour, which is not working from your code, any error you are getting.

Comment: The expected behavior as that items from both lists are rendered in the total . The problem is that either items from one list or the other are considered in the total (and so in the selected property). Please don't modify the fiddle directly and fork it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to refactor quite a lot, tried to stick closely to the way in which you wanted to build the cart. However it really required a bit of rethinking in terms of how you would structure your data:

here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebigsurf/w8vfb64L/11/

**EDIT**

To allow updating more than 1 field on the product object I don't believe you can currently use v-model for this. Therefore instead of setting a v-model on the component pass it a method that you can update any of the items fields via:

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebigsurf/0chtzwjd/2/

```js
var entriesComponent = Vue.component('entries', {

    template: '#entries',
    
    props: {
        item: Object,
        itemKey: String,
        selected: Boolean,
        updateSelected: Function,
        updateItem: Function,
    },
    
    data () {
     return {
         quantity: 0,
            message: '',
        }
    },
    
    created () {
     this.quantity = this.item.quantity
        this.message = this.item.message
    },
    
    watch: {
     quantity () {
         this.updateItem(this.itemKey, 'quantity', this.quantity)
        },
     message () {
         this.updateItem(this.itemKey, 'message', this.message)
        },
    }
    
});

new Vue({

    el: '#app',
    
    data: {
     allProducts: {
         'foo': { shareSize: 'Small', quantity: '1', itemPrice: '24', message: '' }, 
            'bar': { shareSize: 'Medium', quantity: '1', itemPrice: '35', message: '' }, 
            'baz': { shareSize: 'Large', quantity: '1', itemPrice: '46', message: 'hello' },
         'bop': { shareSize: 'Large', quantity: '1', itemPrice: '46', message: '' },
        },
     items: [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ],
        addons: [ 'bop' ],
        selected: {},
        paymentConfig: {
            advance: 25,
            firstweek: 25,
            ondelivery: 50,
        },
        weeks: 12,
    },
    
    components: {
        entriesComponent,
    },
    
    created () {
        this.setSelectableItems()
    },
    
    computed: {
    
        totalAdvance () {
            return (this.paymentConfig.advance * this.total) / 100
        },
        
        totalFirstWeek () {
            return (this.paymentConfig.firstweek * this.total) / 100
        },
        
        onDeliveryPayment () {        
            return (this.paymentConfig.ondelivery * this.total) / (this.weeks * 100)
        },
        
        total() {
        
            var sum = 0
            
            Object.keys(this.selected)
                .forEach((productKey) => {
                 if (this.selected[productKey]) {
                        sum += 
                            this.weeks * 
                            this.allProducts[productKey].itemPrice * 
                            this.allProducts[productKey].quantity
                    }
                })
            
            return sum
            
        },
        
    },

 methods: {
    
     setSelectableItems () {
        
         this.items
                .forEach((productKey) => {
                    Vue.set(this.selected, productKey, false)
                })
                
            this.addons
                .forEach((productKey) => {
                    Vue.set(this.selected, productKey, false)
                })
        
        },
    
     setSelected (productKey, value) {
        
         this.selected[productKey] = value
        
        },
        
        syncItem (key, field, value) {
        
         this.allProducts[key][field] = value
        
        },
    
    },
    
});
```

```css
.row {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.row:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

.item {
    background: #dcdcdc;
    border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.item span {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.item input {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

    <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label required">Items</label>
        <entries 
            v-for="productKey in items"
            :update-item="syncItem"        
            :item="allProducts[productKey]"
            :item-key="productKey"
            :update-selected="setSelected"
            :selected="selected[productKey]"></entries>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label required">Addons</label>
        <entries 
            v-for="productKey in addons"
            :update-item="syncItem"    
            :item="allProducts[productKey]"
            :item-key="productKey"
            :update-selected="setSelected"
            :selected="selected[productKey]"></entries>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <label>Summary</label>
        <div class="item" v-for="(value, productKey) in selected" v-if="value">
            <span>{{ allProducts[productKey].shareSize }}</span>
            <span>
                {{ allProducts[productKey].quantity }}
                 x $
                {{ (allProducts[productKey].itemPrice * allProducts[productKey].quantity).toFixed(2)}}
            </span>
            <span>{{ allProducts[productKey].message }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <label>Payment plan</label>
        <p>{{ '$ ' + totalAdvance.toFixed(2) }} - advance</p>
        <p>{{ '$ ' + totalFirstWeek.toFixed(2) }} - first week</p>
        <p>{{ '$ ' + onDeliveryPayment.toFixed(2) }}/ week on each of the {{ weeks }} weeks of the subscription</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <p>
            <span>Total</span>
            <span>{{ '$ ' + total.toFixed(2) }}</span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <span>Total due now</span>
            <span>{{ '$ ' + totalAdvance.toFixed(2) }}</span>
        </p>
    </div>

</div>


<!-- component template -->
<template id="entries">

    <div class="item">

        <input 
            type="checkbox"
            v-bind:value="selected"
            @change="updateSelected(itemKey, $event.target.checked)">
        
        <span>size: {{item.shareSize}}</span>
        
        <span>price: {{'$ ' + Number(item.itemPrice).toFixed(2) }}</span>
        
        <input type="number" v-model="quantity" />
        
        <input type="text" v-model="message" />

    </div>

</template>
```

Comment: v-model="allProducts[productKey].quantity"  for me should be the entire model. I will not only update the quantity but i will also add some other fields to the item. I was wondering if it isn't best to do a component for each item?

Comment: updated answer to allow for updating multiple fields on the product

Comment: did that sort it for you?

Comment: I actually found a different way of doing this. By using two components with the same template.

Comment: :) fair enough - the above answers the question of how you could sync two lists with a single parent param using the setup you provided. Ideally you should start looking at central state management via vuex as that would allow you to completely isolate each component. However that wasn't what you asked, you wanted "the selected prop to hold items from both lists" so that they are "considered in the total"...